# append one page content into another

Tags: pages, content

I need to append the content of one page into [this one](http://agendadelvolo.info/office/). I have tried to use a plugin which is very easy to use but doesn't work in my case. Then I found following code:

```
<?php $recent = new WP_Query("page_id=**ID**"); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
   <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
```

but it adds only  the title of the page, not the content. PHP is beyond my skills but I believe it's just a matter of adding a line of code inside the first page. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_post_field()` for getting the post fields i.e. Title, Content etc.

```
// Replace $post_id with the ID of your post/page
<?php 
  get_post_field( post_title, $post_id);  
  get_post_field( post_content, $post_id); 
?>
```

Comment: is there a way to upload files in this forum?

Comment: What do you want to upload, Criss? If it's code, use Pastebin service or edit the question.

Comment: because they are templates and not posts, I cannot use any method described to append the page, i.e. this page http://www.mediafire.com/view/lodc1dxafzxfbq4/page-contact-us.php into this page http://www.mediafire.com/view/3b4zu9fu6mavc2l/page-about-us.php

Comment: Try this `<?php get_template_part( 'page', 'contact-us' ); ?>`

Comment: I guess what I'm doing wrong is the place where to insert the new code... this is the end of the main page template: _</div> <!-- end member-details -->
</div> <!-- end grid-layout -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- end .row -->
</div> <!-- end .about-us -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
  
</div> <!-- end .page-content -->
</div> <!-- end .contenitore -->
</div> <!-- end .container -->
</div> <!-- end #page-content -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>_